# how to find linkbutton value on clicking checkbox in datalist using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is what i have done:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Pro
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ContentTemplate>

                                        <div style="height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: Auto">
                                            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Red">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="checkLike_CheckedChanged" />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("UPP")%>' ID="lnkpro" runat="server" CssClass="linkbutton"
                                                        OnClick="btn_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UCode") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>


                                            </asp:DataList>
                                        </div>

                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="services">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Sets
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ContentTemplate>

                                        <div style="height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: Auto">
                                            <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("SNA")%>' ID="lnkpro1" runat="server" CssClass="linkbutton"
                                                        OnClick="btn_Click1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:DataList>
                                        </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Now my question :
This code block results in a list of link buttons in front of them all checkboxes. So what i want is to get the respective linkbutton value on checkbox checkchanged.
 Is it possible? 
for example
[] linkbtn1
[] linkbtn2
when i check on first checkbox the id not text of linkbutton1 should be fetched.([] is checkbox )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of each link button is going to be the same on each row of the data list, the text value of each link button will be the `SNA` value bound to that link button. You can retrieve that `SNA` value by using the check box's `CheckChanged` event, like this:

In the `DataList`'s `ItemTemplate` markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" 
              OnCheckedChanged="checkbox_CheckChanged" />
```

Now that we have wired up the check changed event, it is time to implement the handler, like this:

```
protected void checkbox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    CheckBox theCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;

    // Make sure the cast to check box worked before we try to use it
    if(theCheckBox != null)
    {
        LinkButton theLinkButton = theCheckBox.Parent.FindControl("lnkpro1") as LinkButton;

        // Verify that the link button was found before we try to use it
        if(theLinkButton != null)
        {
            // Get the text value from the link button in the same row 
            // as the check box checked changed
            string theLinkButtonText = theLinkButton.Text;

            // Do something with text value here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so  is it i can't get the linkbutton value?

Comment: @R_sharma - the link button value is the `Text` property.

Comment: ok ok.What i mean is to get CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UCode") %>' and CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("checkbox");
            LinkButton lnkbtnActivate = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("lnkpro");

            if (chk.Checked == true)
            {
                string Result = lnkbtnActivate.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```